# Making a button fixed on a changing DIV

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to allign a button to the center of the DIV.I was able to make it work with different strategies using a padding-top:2px and padding-bottom:2px or with using a margin-top and margin-bottom.But here comes the problem,basically it is a moving DIV i.e it might differ if the user have more inforamtion in it.For example user enters only work number in the input text field it will be showing up only the only work phone number.But if the user enters work,home and additional number,it need to show all the information entered,which will vary the size of the DIV.What happens is the div will increase in size and button still stays at the top of the div.Is there any way to make the button fixed at the center even after the DIV varies in size.Can it be achieved in CSS or we need to used javascript to make it work.

Comment: If I'm reading that right, you want the button vertically centered in the div? Horizontal centering is trivial. Vertical not so much.

Comment: Dear can you please show us code/fiddle/screen shot so we can understand your situation easily, because visually we can identify more efficiently and this helps people to understand your problem.

Comment: For horizontal centering use margin:auto (with no float on the div), for vertical I dont know any other way except javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical align is always tricky.

However where is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/35RdL/) of moving centered button with CSS and moved with jQuery.

As it moves, the button remains at center as the position has not been defined.

```
#outer {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;  
    background: #ddd;
    height: 200px;
    position: static;
    display: table;
}
#inner {
    line-height: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vetical-align: middle;   
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/35RdL/ Is there any possibility that if i add a number of <p> tags the button should be always alligned to the center of the <p> tags.i.e even if the height varies.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done with pure css, is this what you are looking for?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #eeeeee;
    }

    .button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 41%;
        left: 33%;

     }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="Button" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this since it is thinking in the right direction and since this is a nice first answer--however, this will not center it permanently. Since the values of `top` and `left` are relative, it may *seem* centered, but it will not always be. Know what I mean?